# How to Create a Daily schedule with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying create a Trigger in Azure Data Factory that will be trigger once a day from Monday to Friday at 7am. I know this should be simple, but I can't remember to create it. Will the following achieve the result:

[image]

Comment: That should work, assuming you want UTC.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, the above settings are fine to achieve your requirement. Just Make sure you have given correct **Time zone**, **Hours** and **Minutes** as per your requirement and check the `Schedule execution times`.

[image]

Ensure you publish the trigger to activate it.